# PHP: merge two arrays, distinct on first key, sum second key

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array (a => '501', b => '1');
$array2 = array (a => '501', b => '2');
```

The merged array should look like this:

```
$merged_array = array (a => '501', b => '3');
```

I've tried many suggestions, one of them is:

```
 $sums = array();
  foreach (array_keys($array1 + $array2) as $key) {
    $sums[$key] = (isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : 0) + (isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : 0);
  }
```

but this results in:

```
$merged_array = array (a => '1002', b => '3');
```

How should I do this? Any advice is much appreciated

**edit: after reading a few comments I realized I should've been more clear. see below**

4 arrays, note the duplicates in 'a':

```
  $array1 = array (a => '501', b => '1');
  $array2 = array (a => '501', b => '2');
  $array3 = array (a => '505', b => '1');
  $array4 = array (a => '509', b => '1');
```

4 merged arrays and serialized should become *something like*

```
a:2:{s:1:"a";i:501;s:1:"b";i:3; s:1:"a";i:505;s:1:"b";i:1; s:1:"a";i:509;s:1:"b";i:1;}
```

so: 2x a => '501' becomes 1x a => '501' and it's 'b' keys become '3' (summed)

and: 1x a=> '505' and b => '1'

and: 1x a=> '509' and b => '1'

Comment: Do the arrays always have two keys? Are the two keys always the same? Are the keys fixed?

Comment: the keys 'a' can differ, these can be 501 - 502 - 503 for example. the keys 'b' can also differ. 'a' may never be duplicated, instead 'a' should be merged.

Comment: What should the a key be in the merged array if the values are different?

Comment: thanks for responding, you made me realize I should've formulated my question in a different way, please see the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an array with the 'a' value as key and the 'b' value as value

```
function map_a_to_b($array) {
    return array($array['a'] => $array['b'];
}
```

Apply `map_a_to_b` to all your input arrays. Then you can merge the arrays recursively:

```
$merged = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);
```

The result will be (for your example):

```
  array ('501' => array('1', '2'),
         '505' => '1',
         '509' => '1')
```

Now sum the inner arrays like that:

```
$summed = array_map(function($item) { return array_sum((array) $item); }, $merged);
```

And convert the key-value array back to your a/b structure. I don't know how exactly it should look like because I can't read serialized arrays fluently. So if you need help with that, please show the desired output as unserialized array.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array1 = array (a => '501', b => '1');
$array2 = array (a => '501', b => '2');

function super_merge($a1, $a2)
{
  $a = array();
  $k_ar = array_keys($a1 + $a2);

  foreach ($k_ar as $k)
  {
    if (isset($a1[$k]) && isset($a2[$k]) && $a1[$k] == $a2[$k])
      $a[$k] = $a1[$k];
    else
      $a[$k] = (isset($a1[$k]) ? $a1[$k] : 0) + (isset($a2[$k]) ? $a2[$k] : 0);
  }

  return $a;
}

var_dump(super_merge($array1, $array2));
```

Comment: thanks dimaninc, you're solution is really close. The output made me realize I didn't formulate my question well. Please see the updated question

Comment: i've read your update but still don't understand what do you exactly need :) please show all three or four input arrays unserialized form and the output output array in unserialized form, then i would try to help you